# Using selenium and webdriver opening up blank webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, webdriver

So I just wanted to get a webpage up using chromedriver

This is the code i am using:
from selenium import webdriver

```
url = "wow.com"

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/macbook/Desktop/chromedriver")

driver.get(url)
```

When I go to run it this is how it appears:

[image]

I checked my version: Version 90.0.4430.93
Its the same one as the chromedriver I downloaded

Still comes up blank

Any solutions?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried with the entire url: https://www.wow.com/ ? Sometimes webdriver can not search the webpage due the url sintaxis.
It is a good practice to add it complete.

This work for me without problem:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.wow.com/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/MY_FOLDER/chromedriver.exe") # WINDOWS
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: thank you so much i cant believe i didnt figure out such an easy solution

Answer (score 3):

Was able to replicate issue with an error on `driver.get(url)` that was not included in the question:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.93)
```

You need to pass the whole url to the `get()` method, otherwise this error will be raised again.

```
driver.get('google.com') # -> InvalidArgumentException
driver.get('www.google.com') # -> InvalidArgumentException
driver.get('https://www.google.com') # -> Works
```

So, you should pass the whole url.